# Hide current submenu when other menu item is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a header where I am having submenus and all. If I click on a menu where I have submenus for those menus it is working fine. But the problem is when I click on another menu which has submenus the previous one which we have clicked is not getting hidden. Both the menus are displaying which is active and inactive mode. Here is the code which I have written:

```js
//Javascript Code:
$('.main-menu li a + ul').prev('a').append('<span class="caret"></span>');
$('.main-menu ul li a').click(function (e) {
  if ($(this).next().hasClass('sub-menu')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // $('.sub-menu').slideUp(); // <--- This is the culprit
    $('.main-menu ul li a').removeClass('active');
    if ($(this).next('.sub-menu').is(':visible')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideUp();
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/*CSS:*/
.main-menu {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.main-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.main-menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.main-menu ul li a {
  padding: 42px 25px;
  color: #898E94;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-family: 'Roboto_reg';
}

.side-nav {
  width: 340px;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #222222;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
  height: auto;
}

.side-nav ul li li a {
  padding-left: 70px;
  font-family: 'source_sans_proregular';
}

.side-nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #ff3c1f;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.side-nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

.side-nav.active {
  display: block;
}

.side-nav ul li ul {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 60, 31, 0.3);
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.side-nav ul li a.active {
  border-color: rgba(255, 60, 31, 0.3);
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.side-nav ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.caret {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 20px;
  right: 65px;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.sub-menu li a {
  padding: 10px 25px !important;
  line-height: 0px !important;
  margin-top: -22px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
  margin-left: -237px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- HTML: -->
<div class="main-menu">
   <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
      <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/barcoun/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/barcoun/about-us/"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
      <li  class="menu-item">
         <a href="#" ><span>Menu3</span><span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/bar/sumenu1/" ><span>submenu1</span></a></li>
            <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/bar/submenu2"><span>submenu2</span></a></li>
            <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/bar/sumenu5/" ><span>submenu5</span></a></li>
            <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/bar/sumenu6/" ><span >submenu6</span></a></li>
            <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/bar/sumenu7/" ><span>submenu7</span></a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
         <a href="#"><span>Other Links</span><span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/bar/sumenu8/" ><span>Submenu8</span></a></li>
            <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/bar/sumenu9/" ><span>Submenu9</span></a></li>
            <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/bar/sumenu10/" ><span>Submenu10</span></a></li>
            <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/bar/sumenu11/" ><span>Submenu11</span></a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/barcoun/contact-us/"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

It is not displaying the arrow icon as well it is working fine in Mobile devices but getting problem in desktops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've edited your JavaScript Code to allow for toggling and hiding other active sub menus.

Edit: Edited css to fix the layout.

```js
$('.main-menu ul li a').click(function (e) {
  // remove the active class with every click
  var same = $(this).hasClass('active');
  var siblings = $(this).parent('.menu-item').parent().children();
  siblings.find('a.active + .sub-menu').slideUp();
  siblings.find('a').removeClass('active'); 
  
  if ($(this).next().hasClass('sub-menu') && !same) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideDown();
  }
});
```

```css
/*CSS:*/
.main-menu {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-item {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.sub-menu {
  padding-left: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.sub-menu.level-2 {
  left: 100%;
}

.caret {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 7px 7px 0 7px;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.menu-item a.active .caret {
  border-width: 0 7px 7px 7px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #000 transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- HTML: -->
<div class="main-menu">
   <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
      <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/barcoun/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/barcoun/about-us/"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
      <li  class="menu-item">
         <a href="#" ><span>Menu3</span><span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/bar/sumenu1/" ><span>submenu1</span></a></li>
            <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/bar/submenu2"><span>submenu2</span></a></li>
            <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/bar/sumenu5/" ><span>submenu5</span></a></li>
            <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/bar/sumenu6/" ><span >submenu6</span></a></li>
            <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/bar/sumenu7/" ><span>submenu7</span></a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
         <a href="#"><span>Other Links</span><span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li  class="menu-item"><a href="#">
              <span>Other Links</span><span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="sub-menu level-2">
                 <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/bar/sumenu9/" ><span>SubSubMenu</span></a></li>
               </ul>
             </li>
            <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/bar/sumenu9/" ><span>Submenu9</span></a></li>
            <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/bar/sumenu10/" ><span>Submenu10</span></a></li>
            <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/bar/sumenu11/" ><span>Submenu11</span></a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li  class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/barcoun/contact-us/"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have checked for other links the sub menus are getting overlapped one on one

Comment: Yes because your css is a mess my friend :) A second please, ill fix it.

Comment: @tester I've edited the css to get a workable solution.

Comment: only those css need to be added rest of the css  should remove

Comment: Fixed your caret. Sorry but i dont understand what you mean with "only those css need to be added rest of the css should remove".

Comment: Their was issue in that if their are sub menus under sub menus then it is not working

Comment: That is not an issue, because it wasnt an requirement.

Comment: Earlier the javascript which i have kept in my issue in that it qas working the js which you have added it has not working

Comment: @tester fixed it, but you should be able to do it yourself... this is my last fix, you should be able to understand how you can solve this problem yourself by now!